# Join map and refer to its key/value in HQL

Tags: hibernate, dictionary, hql

Suppose I have a map:

```xml
        <map name="externalIds" table="album_external_ids">
            <key column="album_id" not-null="true"/>
            <map-key-many-to-many class="Major" column="major_id"/>
            <element column="external_id" type="string" not-null="true"/>
        </map>
```

How do I make a HQL meaning "select entities where map key's id == :foo and map value == :bar"?

I can join it using `select album from Album album join album.externalIds ids`
But how would I then refer to ids' key and value?
ids.key.id = :foo and ids.value = :bar doesn't work, and hibernate doc is silent on this topic.

Naive approaches that didn't work:

```sql
select album 
from Album album 
join album.externalIds externalId
    where index(externalId).id = :foo and externalId = :bar
```

and

```sql
select album 
from Album album 
join album.externalIds externalId 
join index(externalId) major
    where major.id = :foo and externalId = :bar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that your query should look like:

```
select album from Album album where album.externalIds['foo'] = 'bar'
```

Hope that helps,

Vincent Giguère

Comment: In query "select album from Album album where album.externalIds['foo'] = 'bar'
", foo and bar should be object not id of object then only this query may work.

Comment: It does work for me, when inner join is what I need. But when I need a left join, it seems like there is no solution. (bwe, "where  album.externalIds['foo1'] = 'bar' or album.externalIds['foo2'] = 'bar'", and using "isNull(album.externalIds['foo1'], '')" does not help since the genereted SQL performs an inner join equivalent)